# How to setup and backup in Time Machine when there is only one hard drive showing?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, backup

[image: Hi, i want to know that how to setup time machine,when i click to on time machine it shows me "other airport time capsule" ![]

then other window open which shows internet written their and they says no airpot found searching for it....![2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe9v3.png)
and if i go to disk utility there is only one hard drive shows "machinetosh hd"![2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe9v3.png)
i have no idea what to do now.i want backup my pc.need help!
*I m new on mac world*

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250

Main thing: you need any other hard drive, whatever ssd, hdd, connected to mac by wi-fi, thunderbolt or usb.

Time Capsule is just one of the many variants.

You can make your backup on any device that you already have. But make a note that it better should be fully given for backup, no any other sided information on a drive, particularly when encrypting your external drive.